# Is it possible to extend some other class and implement RealmModel?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to extend my model from a `BaseModel` and then implement `RealmModel`.

```
@RealmClass
public class User extend BaseModel implements RealmModel
```

But it is  throwing an error:

`error: Realm model classes must either extend RealmObject or implement RealmModel to be considered a valid model class`

Please help.

Comment: You can't. Check this answer to get a clear idea of how to workaround this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/41552457/3503855

Comment: But then what's the point of RealmModel interface.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Realm's GitHub repository, inheritance and polymorphism are not implemented in Realm just yet.

As one of the contributors [described it](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2643):

> Realm currently is using byte code manipulation to replace field accessors and using annotation processor to create proxy classes. Enabling RealmObject to extend from the other class/abstract class will increase a bit complexity of Realm. So it is not implemented right now. But I agree it is something we should support.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761).

I guess that for the time being, you will have to think of another way to write your classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unfortunate, but `RealmModel` exists so that you don't need to inherit properties and methods from `RealmObject`.

I tried extending a base class that only contained fields annotated with `@Ignore`, but [even that is not supported at the moment](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3395).

Only way to "share fields" is to share the accessors through interface.