# Polymorphic relations in realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

```
IBaseA   <--- Interface
CBaseB   <--- Concrete base class

ChildA implements IBaseA{
    //fields and getters, setters
}

ChildB extends CBaseB, implements IBaseA{
    //fields and getters, setters  
}

TestClass implements RealmModel{
    private IBaseA child_obj;
}
```

The intention for making TestClass this way was to be able to assign any of ChildA or ChildB objects to TestClass.child_obj, and still be able to let ChildA and ChildB implement other interfaces as required.

However, this causes a compile-time exception

```
Error:(12, 8) error: Type 'in.avanti_app.student_companion.realmClasses.TestClass' of field 'child_obj' is not supported
```

How we can achieve the above intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a RealmObject for each concrete class, flattening the bases into the RealmObjects. Share the field accessors with common interfaces.

Read [this github comment](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761#issuecomment-258299398)

and

[Composition over inheritance for RealmObjects with Gson serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259735/composition-over-inheritance-for-realmobjects-with-gson-serialization/42270644#42270644)

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphism and inheritance are not supported by Realm. You can follow this issue for updates: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761

Generally we recommend Composition instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance, but in your situation that probably isn't ideal since it would look something like this:

`public class IBaseA extends RealmObject {
  ChildA childA;
  ChildB childB;
}`